# Cisco 1800 series: sys-2-chunkexpanfail: error every time

Tags: cisco, router, troubleshooting

[image]

My knowledge of Cisco is very basic and I´m having this error constantly. I have to reboot every time, and it does not seem right. How can I solve it at once?? What I know of this device is that it has set up a VPN account and other Internet whenever I get the error Internet connection is cut, but not the VPN.

Comment: Please don't use pictures for text in your question or an answer. Copy the text and paste it into your question.

Comment: Are you able to do a "#show proc mem" command? It appears your router has run out of available memory space or you have hit a bug. I would wager a restart would stop this error temporarily but after a while, you will hit the same problem again.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on release **12.4(15)T12 | 12.4(24)T2** then this could be related to a Cisco bug *CSCtg26917* with more details on it [here](https://quickview.cloudapps.cisco.com/quickview/bug/CSCtg26917)

**Symptom:**

> Chunk manager consume almost all memory. We found the issue is related
>   to NAT

**Conditions:**

> The memory hold by chunk manager increased quickly while NAT translate
>   increased rapidly.

If you are using NAT and are on this version of IOS, it would be adviseable for you to do an upgrade of the firmware.

Answer (score -1):

#### [Cisco 1800 Series Integrated Services Routers Fixed Configuration Models](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/1801-integrated-services-router-isr/product_data_sheet0900aecd8028a95f.html)

> The default memory of 32 MB Flash and 128 MB DRAM is sufficient to
> support complex configurations and help ensure operation for an
> extended period. Memory is expandable to support maximum of 128 MB
> Flash and 384 MB DRAM, offering additional investment protection.

#### [Portable Product Sheets – Routing Performance](https://www.cisco.com/web/partners/downloads/765/tools/quickreference/routerperformance.pdf)

[image]